# <audio> src change with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I want to change the src attribute of a  tag using javascript and a button :

```
<audio id="playme" src="" controls="controls">Your browser...</audio>
```

And a little further down the page :

```
<input type="button" style="font-size: 10px;"
        OnClick="document.getElementById('playme').src='snd/SOUND.WAV';"
        value="Listen">
```

It seems to just do nothing. Anyone has a clue ? Thanks a million

Using Firefox 3.6 on Xubuntu 10.10

**EDIT** : it seems to work on Chrome but Firefox doesn't like it. Should I report a bug ? Do you know a way to bypass that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you have to tell the browser to load the new file when you change the `src` attribute, by calling `load`:

```
var playme = document.getElementById('playme'); playme.src='snd/SOUND.WAV'; playme.load();
```

Comment: This works great for .wav and .mp3 files. .ogg files work on a PC running Chrome, Firefox or Safari. However mobile safari(iOS) and Android (Firefox and Chrome fail to see the sounds. can the "type" be updated this way as well? like type="xx" in the <Audio> tags?